# Displaying an Array Value in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to rails (rather, a slow learner).

I have a profile model and an industry model. Profiles belong to industries.

In my profile show page, I have this line:

```
  <span class="profilefield"> <%= @profile.industry_id %></span>
```

Industry id is the foreign key in the profiles table. When users create their profile they select their industry. The form has an array that lists industries with associated numbers, as follows:

```
  <%= f.input :industry_id, label: 'Select your industry sector', collection: [["Agriculture", 1], ["Construction", 2], ["Food", 3], ["Manufacturing", 4], ["Medical Devices", 5]], prompt: "Choose one" %> </div>
```

In my industry table, I have an attribute called 'sector' which has those sectors in it.

In my profiles controller, I have whitelisted params for industry_id, but now im wondering if I need to whitelist industry_sector or something else because all I can do in the show page for profiles is show the number associated with the array rather than the value attached to it.

Does anyone know what I've done wrong?

Thank you

Comment: try `collection_select(:industry, :industry_id, Industry.all, :id, :sector, {prompt: "Choose one"})`

Comment: Hi Sontya, thanks for the suggestion, but the view still displays the number rather than the associated value (industry sector name)

Comment: what sector field in industries database has?

Comment: Actually, my save didn't work when I tested this suggestion. I just tried it again and I get this error message: undefined method `merge' for :sector:Symbol

Comment: You can also try `f.select("industry", "industry_id", Industry.all.collect {|p| [ p.sector, p.id ] }, {prompt: 'Choose One'})`

Comment: Hi, thanks for sticking with me - now i get this error: 
undefined method `merge' for [[nil, 1]]:Array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73914/discussion-between-sontya-and-user2860931).

Comment: show me, what you have in sector field?